# How to implement miles away like Tinder in Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, location

I am trying to calculate how many miles away the user is from another user. Like on Tinder.

I am using Firebase to store all of the users data related to the app.

What would be the most secure way to do this without storing the actual users current location?

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the current location, and after calculating the distance or after the user logs out, delete the location from the database.  That is the only way to do it.
Note that this will work only if both users are online at the same time.

Comment: I read in an article that Tinder stores the longitude and latitude in its database, then when a user needs to know how many miles away someone is they calculate the distance on the server side then send the miles to the user instead of the coordinates.

Comment: yeah even you can do that, but you said you didnt want to store the location, "What would be the most secure way to do this without storing the actual users current location"

Comment: Oh okay, I see what you mean. I will try that out with the launch of the app and see if it causes any problems for people. I would like to figure out a way to store just the coordinates of the user then use a different language to process how many miles away the user is then just send that data to the user fetching it.